# Nuxt3 aliases for directories in nuxtconfig

Tags: nuxt.js, config, alias, nuxtjs3

I would like to create aliases for some directories in a Nuxt 3 project, however, I was not able to make them work just from the information provided in the documentation.

I've tried registering them like this:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    alias {
        "@scss": "/<rootDir>/assets/scss",
    }
})
```

as well as like this:

```js
import {fileURLToPath} from "url";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    alias {
        "@scss": fileURLToPath(new URL('./assets/scss', import.meta.url)),
    }
})
```

and then using them in vue components like this:

```html
<style lang="scss">
@use "~@sass/............";    // one way (because the documentation says sth about prefixing it with '~'

@use "@sass/............";
</style>
```

and as you can probably imagine, it did not work .

What is the proper way to register an alias for a folder and then use it in css, javascript & template markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should use `dart-sass` instead of `node-sass` package since it doesn't support the `@use` method.
Also install `url` if it's not already there and import `fileURLToPath` explicitly in your `nuxt.config` file.

`import {fileURLToPath} from 'url';`

I made an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt3-playground-forked-70cvum?file=/nuxt.config.js)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! So the second example I provided was correct... strange that it didn't work for me when I tried it before - but now it works!